# Upload a war without manager on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, war

In my local environment, I have way to deploy a app using the manager of Tomcat.

Now I need to upload a war to production environment, but I don't have the tomcat manager on the web host, how do I do this?

Comment: Do you have `ssh` access to the server?  If yes, do you have `sudo` privileges or write-access to the Tomcat directories?

Comment: @JimGarrison, yes i have access ssh, and write-access to the Tomcat directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is a linux you can to copy your war file to webapps folder on server.

Example:

```
copy file.war /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/
```

Put your war in this folder.